# create-react-app circle build failed

Tags: create-react-app, circleci

## !/bin/bash -eo pipefail

yarn build
yarn run v1.6.0
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:364:12)
    at PoolWorker.writeJson (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:89:22)
    at PoolWorker.run (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:69:12)
    at WorkerPool.distributeJob (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:326:20)
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/queue.js:10:5
    at Object.process (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/queue.js:175:17)
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/queue.js:115:15
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at callback (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:163:21)
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:190:15
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/map.js:32:9
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at replenish (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:50:17)
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/thread-loader/node_modules/async/internal/map.js:29:13
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 1

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I am running into this now

Comment: Running into it too. I tried removing thread-loader from webpack config but now it's stuck at "Creating an optimized production build..."

Comment: I'm also seeing this.  Did you find a solution?